# Does xcorr in matplotlib return the cross correlation coefficient?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The docstring for xcorr confused me a bit. I know it is supposed to do a cross correlation, and I know it is supposed to return the number of lags, the coefficients (c), and the plot of the coefficients. This is if you feed the function two different arrays. However, the docstring for xcorr said that c is the `auto correlation vector.` Shouldn't it be cross correlation if you fed the function two different arrays? Here is the link: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr.html

I believe the docstring may have a mistake on it. I tested out the function on two arrays `x` and `y`. I compared `plt.xcorr(x,y)` and `plt.acorr(x)` and they both returned different coefficients. I also compared `plt.xcorr(x,y)`, `plt.xcorr(x,x)`, and `plt.xcorr(y,y)`, they all returned different results. If `plt.xcorr(x,y)` was to return the auto correlation vector, then it would have outputted the same results as `plt.xcorr(x,x)` or `plt.xcorr(y,y)`. This makes me believe that the docstring may have a typo on it, but I just want to make sure because I will be using this function in my code for a project.

Comment: This is just an error in the docs resulting from copying the docstring from one function to the other. You are welcome to submit a fix on github.

Comment: Thank you so much!